# Cannot find module 'table-hints' when running a sequelize powered express app

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, nodes, yarnpkg

I am having an issue with my ExpressJS app using sequelize. When I run the app, I get this message:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
  throw e;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 
'C:\node_projects\my_app\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\table-hints'
```

This issue started happening after I edited one of my app's routes, which has nothing to do with app initialization. I cannot share code, because it seems to be a problem within sequelize itself.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "my_app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "nodemon index.js",
 "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
 "dexy": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\" ",
 "test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha tests.js --timeout 10000"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"bluebird": "^3.7.2",
"body-parser": "^1.19.1",
"cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
"ejs": "^3.1.6",
"express": "^4.17.2",
"express-validation": "^3.0.8",
"express-validator": "^6.14.0",
"helmet": "^4.6.0",
"joi": "^17.5.0",
"mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"passport": "^0.5.2",
"passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
"passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"pg": "^8.7.1",
"request": "^2.88.2",
"request-promise": "^4.2.6",
"sequelize": "^6.12.2",
"tedious": "^14.0.0",
"uuid": "^8.3.2"
}
  }
```

The code I use to init my db is like this:

```
function dbInit(app){
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const sqlCon = new Sequelize(keys.dbName,keys.dbUser, keys.dbPassword,
{dialect:'postgresql',
 host:keys.dbHost,
 pool:20,
 logging:false
});

app.locals.connection = sqlCon;

//wire up model definitions
const User = require('../models/User')(sqlCon,sequelize);
const PasswordResetRequest = require('../models/PasswordResetRequest')(sqlCon,sequelize);
const CertType =require('../models/CertType')(sqlCon,sequelize);
const Role =require('../models/Role')(sqlCon,sequelize);

app.locals.User = User;
app.locals.PasswordResetRequest = PasswordResetRequest;
app.locals.CertType = CertType;
app.locals.Role = Role;


//setup relationships between tables
require('../models/relationships')(app);

sqlCon.sync().then(()=>{
    return sqlCon.authenticate()
})
    .catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Successfully NOT connected to DB!');
    console.log(err);
});
return sqlCon;
```

}

Can anyone shed any light on why this error happens? Thanks! I already downgraded sequelize from version 7-aplha2.

Comment: Did you check if `sequelize\dist\lib\table-hints` exists?

Comment: It seems that my IDE added a require command apparently on its own accord for this file. I solved it by removing the offending require. Still have no idea how it happened.